# Расположить n число елементов в полукруге

Tags: javascript, css

Как можно расположить n число елементов в полукруге? Как на скрине.
[image: скрин]

На круге их можно расположить подобным образом:

```js
    var circle = document.getElementById('box'),
        imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        total = imgs.length,
        coords = {},
        diam, radius1, radius2, imgW;

    // get circle diameter
    // getBoundingClientRect outputs the actual px AFTER transform
    //      using getComputedStyle does the job as we want
    diam = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle(circle).getPropertyValue('width') ),
    radius = diam/2,
    imgW = imgs[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
    // get the dimensions of the inner circle we want the images to align to
    radius2 = radius - imgW

    var i,
        alpha = Math.PI / 2,
        len = imgs.length,
        corner = 2 * Math.PI / total;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < total; i++ ){

      imgs[i].style.left = parseInt( ( radius - imgW / 2 ) + ( radius2 * Math.cos( alpha ) ) ) + 'px'
      imgs[i].style.top =  parseInt( ( radius - imgW / 2 ) - ( radius2 * Math.sin( alpha ) ) ) + 'px'

      alpha = alpha - corner;
    }
```

```css
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body{
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    #box{
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid teal;
    }
    .dot{
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        background: rebeccapurple;
    }
    #box img{
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="box">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <img id="" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/"/>
    <img id="" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/"/>
    <img id="" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/"/>
    <img id="" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/"/>
    <img id="" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить диапазон всех углов окружности, разделив его на 2,
задать другую начальную точку, и, для более корректного распределения элементов по дуге скорректировать формулу.

В вашем js коде это 11 строка:

```
alpha = Math.PI * (3/2),
```

и 13 строка:

```
corner =  Math.PI / (total-1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5c3n1x84/31/

Comment: cпасибо, правда я не совсем понял почему -1

Comment: При расчете расположения картинок каждому элементу резервируется место и отступ до следующего элемента. Ставя -1 мы убираем пустое место после последней картинки.

Comment: А в исходном варианте это было не нужно, т.к. после последнего элемента снова шел первый, и отступ был необходим